# Не переведена фраза о существовании мобильного приложения

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В мобильной версии сайта не переведена фраза

> Read this post in our app!

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: This string is on [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/91127398?q=Read%20this%20post%20in%20our%20app!)